# Error Code 91 - Object or Variable on Set VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to execute the following code on excel opening in vba but it is giving me error Object or With block Variable not set. I have written the following function to execute my functionality.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim FilePath As String
Dim AccessPath As String

FilePath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
AccessPath = FilePath & "\ABC Data.accdb"

 With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ABC DATA_V1").OLEDBConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .CommandText = Array("ABCDataTest")
    .CommandType = xlCmdTable
    .Connection = Array( _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Password="""";User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & AccessPath & ";" _
    , _
    "Mode=Share Deny Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";" _
    , _
    "Jet OLEDB:Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet" _
    , _
    " OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Da" _
    , _
    "tabase=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet" _
    , _
    " OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass" _
    , " ChoiceField Validation=False")
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .SavePassword = False
    .SourceConnectionFile = ""
    .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
    .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
End With
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ABC DATA_V1")
    .Name = "ABC DATA_V1"
    .Description = ""
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ABC DATA_V1").Refresh


End Sub
```

When I try to debug , it is working fine if executed line by line but on file open it gives me error in the first **With** block(With ActiveWorkbook.Connections...).

Comment: On `Workbook.Open` its probably enough if you just call `ThisWorkbook.Connections("ABC DATA_V1").Refresh`. Is it trying to create a table? Also give the exact line where the error occurs.

Comment: I am trying to link access db to pivot table.The exact error comes at the first With block.

Comment: The databases have different paths in different systems so I was creating a code to pick path dynamically.

Comment: Is there an connection with the name `"ABC DATA_V1"` ? you are using an existent one, so make sure its created.

Comment: Yes there is a connection. The connection is already created. Only the path of db gets changed.

Comment: There may be a timing problem. Try with nested `With` statements: `With ActiveWorkbook \nWith .Connections("ABC DATA_V1")\n With .OLEDBConnection` and see where it fails. (`\n` means newline.)